# How to mount an Azure file share on Android?

Tags: mount, cifs

I tried a couple of Android file explorer apps to mount an (SMB3) Azure file share, but I got an "Access Denied" error with each of them.

Does anyone know a solution?

I tried the most common File-Apps on PlayStore:

- Cx File Explorer
- File Manager
- X-plore
- AndSMB
- CIFS Documents Provider

Authentication is with username and Azure storage account key based on the snippet provided by azure for Linux:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/fileshare1
if [ ! -d "/etc/smbcredentials" ]; then
sudo mkdir /etc/smbcredentials
fi
if [ ! -f "/etc/smbcredentials/aname.cred" ]; then
    sudo bash -c 'echo "username=aname" >> /etc/smbcredentials/aname.cred'
    sudo bash -c 'echo "password=akey" >> /etc/smbcredentials/aname.cred'
fi
sudo chmod 600 /etc/smbcredentials/aname.cred

sudo bash -c 'echo "//aname.file.core.windows.net/fileshare1 /mnt/fileshare1 cifs nofail,vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/aname.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino" >> /etc/fstab'
sudo mount -t cifs //aname.file.core.windows.net/fileshare1 /mnt/fileshare1 -o vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/aname.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
```

Comment: Which apps have you tried: do they claim to have SMB3 support because at Azure requires SMB 3.0 or 3.1 support? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows What credentials have you used (e.g. pattern of user-name). Please edit your question and add those details.